# Show a random quote on asp.net web page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm working on an ASP.NET (C#) web project that is using master pages.

I'm looking for an easy way to display a random customer quote each time a page is loaded.

Since this is a fairly simple web project I'd like to stay away from storing the quotes in a database. Currently there is no database connections required for the project so I'd like to keep it as simple as possible -- perhaps storing the quotes in an XML file them using an XmlTextReader to read the file?

Any advice is appreciated.

Thanks

**Edit:** I will need to store and pull both a quote and a customer name for the quote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It could be something as simple as this with LINQ:

```
XElement xml = new XElement("quotes",
    new XElement("quote",
        new XElement("customer", "Customer #1"),
        new XElement("text", "Quote #1")),
    new XElement("quote",
        new XElement("customer", "Customer #2"),
        new XElement("text", "Quote #2")),
    new XElement("quote",
        new XElement("customer", "Customer #3"),
        new XElement("text", "Quote #3")),
    new XElement("quote",
        new XElement("customer", "Customer #4"),
        new XElement("text", "Quote #4")),
    new XElement("quote",
        new XElement("customer", "Customer #5"),
        new XElement("text", "Quote #5"))
);

//XElement xml = XElement.Load("filename"); // use file instead of above
var result = xml.Elements()
                .OrderBy(r => System.Guid.NewGuid())
                .Select(element => new { 
                        Customer = element.Element("customer").Value,
                        Quote = element.Element("text").Value
                    })
                .First();

Console.WriteLine("{0} : {1}", result.Customer, result.Quote);
```

Your file would be structured like this:

```
<quotes>
  <quote>
    <customer>Customer #1</customer>
    <text>Quote #1</text>
  </quote>
  <quote>
    <customer>Customer #2</customer>
    <text>Quote #2</text>
  </quote>
  <quote>
    <customer>Customer #3</customer>
    <text>Quote #3</text>
  </quote>
  <quote>
    <customer>Customer #4</customer>
    <text>Quote #4</text>
  </quote>
  <quote>
    <customer>Customer #5</customer>
    <text>Quote #5</text>
  </quote>
</quotes>
```

You would load it using `XElement xml = XElement.Load("filename");`

With the `xml` variable above, the previous code is used the same way (commented out code).

The `Guid` works but you could also have a static Random variable defined in a class: `public static Random rand = new Random();` then change the code to:

```
int count = xml.Elements().Count();
var randomQuote = xml.Elements()
                     .OrderBy(i => rand.Next(0, count))
                     .Select(element => new { 
                        Customer = element.Element("customer").Value,
                        Quote = element.Element("text").Value
                      })
                     .First();

Console.WriteLine("{0} : {1}", result.Customer, result.Quote);
```

Comment: Updated to account for new customer requirement

Answer (score 4):

If you want simple: store it as a plain text file with each quote separated by a newline, read in the entire file using [`File.ReadAllText()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalltext.aspx), split on the newlines to make an array, and pick a random index of that array for your quote.

Example file:

> Quote 1 blah blah blah.
>   Quote 2 lorem ipsum dolor...

Example code:

```
string[] quotes = File.ReadAllText("path/to/quotes.txt")
          .Split(new string[] { "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
string randomQuote = quotes[new Random().Next(0, quotes.Length)];
```

Comment: I have updated my original post to reflect that I actually need to store and pull a quote and customer name. Therefore the single line approach might be too limited, unless I stored the quote and customer name on the single line with a delimiter. Then parsed the string on the delimiter.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you answered you own question. You can store the quotes in an xml file and then just add them to an array and display one value from the array one at a time...